# How to make background div not count in scrollable area

Tags: html, css, scroll, viewport

I have a situation where I need to create a div element which is wider a viewport defined by another div. If tried changing border, padding, and margin of the various divs without much luck.

Here's the CSS:

```
#page_content {
    width:200px;
}

#content_container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color:#999999;
}

#content_inner {
    padding:20px;
}
```

and the html

```
<div id="page_content">
    <div id="content_container">
        <div id="content_inner">
            <div  style="height: 100px; width: 200px; background-color:#ff0000;">
                <div style="height: 10px; width: 500px; background-color:#ffff00;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBfdZ/1/)

What I would like is for the scrollable area to be limited to 20px past the red div, but the yellow div needs to be a fair bit wider than the viewport

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/gBfdZ/2/ ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need the inner div to scroll...

Comment: I am lost, what is the final result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pUy4D/ is a more complete example of what I am doing. I need the extra space to the right of the hexagons so they render correctly. But I don't want to be able to scroll past the edge of the red div, otherwise I end up seeing blank space where part of a hexagon should otherwise be

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :)

css

```
#page_content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:auto;
}

#content_container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

#content_inner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.hex-row {
    margin-left: 17px;
    height: 50px;
    clear: left;
}

.hex-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    margin-bottom: -24px;
}

.hex-wrapper.even {
    margin-top: 27px;
}

.hex {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #114781;
}

.hex:before,  .hex:after{
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

.hex:before {
    left: -15px;
    border-right: 15px solid #114781;
}

.hex:after {
    right: -15px;
    border-left: 15px solid #114781;
}
```

html

```
<div id="page_content">
    <div id="content_container">
        <div id="content_inner">
            <div style="width: 250px; height: 300px; background-color:#ff0000;">
                <div style="width: 280px;  height: 300px; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -30px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
                    <div style="height: 750; overflow-y: visible;">
                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="hex-row" style="width: 550px; overflow-x: visible;">
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                            <div class="hex-wrapper even"><div class="hex"></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUy4D/1/)

The trick was to create a viewport div with hidden overflow with a larger content div inside with visible overflow

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this in my project, i created a css like this

```
div.scrolled {
  width: 1150px;
  height: 620px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and in my html file i only identify what area i want to introduce into my div and i do this

```
div class="scrolled">
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

and you will have your scroll in 'y' align, hope i helped you

Comment: I need both the inner and outer div to scroll, but only to the extent of the outer div. The inner div has content that needs room to render beyond the scrollable area.

Comment: well in your code seems to be that you want a scrollable area that contains your "content_inner", because in your css for this inner doesn't have an overflow...if you want to add to the inner an scroll you only have to add the overflow as it has the class scrolled (like in my example)...i will be attent to your problem, comment how it goes...